# Difficulty Graphing Excel Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'd like to create an appropriate graph for the following sort of data. I'm using an example as the actual data is 1000+ lines.

```
Date         Player       Points

02/06/2014   Bob          2500
03/06/2014   Bob          4000
04/06/2014   Bob          5100
02/06/2014   Steve        1000
03/06/2014   Steve        1500
04/06/2014   Steve        3600
02/06/2014   Sam          5000
03/06/2014   Sam          3700
04/06/2014   Sam          4100
```

I'd like the graph to track each player's progress over time. Ideally a line graph. I am having trouble with excel trying to do this.

Comment: How many players are there (i.e., how many lines on your graph)?

Comment: In the actual data there is 20 players, with about 90 lines each - so approx. 1800 altogether. It tracks their progress every day over the last 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table and pivot chart will do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Line-Graph-in-Microsoft-Excel) you can easy get such kind of line graph:

[image]

If you have about 20 players, you will possibly want to create the separate graph per player.

Comment: Let's say you made a graph per player, would there be a way of merging each? For instance having each line on a single graph?

Comment: Not sure having undersood your goal: imagine for this example with 3 players simple 3 separated graphs each with 3 lines...

Comment: I am talking about 1 graph with 3 lines, a line for each player.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the players into separate series using formulas. In the screenshot below, you can see how I've added three columns, one per player, with the player's name in the first row. The formula in cell D2, which is copied and pasted into D2:F10, is

`=IF($B2=D$1,$C2,NA())`

The #N/A in the cells will not be plotted in a line chart, and is fine in a column chart if you don't add data labels.

Select the shaded areas (select one area, then hold Ctrl while selecting additional areas) and insert a line chart. The default is the top chart, which might be all you need. It all depends on how you want to show the data, and even if you settle on this for the report for your boss, it never hurts to spend a few minutes looking at alternative charts.

If you change the X axis from Automatic (Excel uses a Date axis if it recognizes the dates in column A) to Text, you get the line chart in the middle. Same data, but further separated by player.

You could change the second chart to a column chart as shown in the bottom chart, and the players are plotted as columns, again separated by player. You should change the series overlap to 100 and gap width also to 100.

[image: Use formulas to split players into separate series]

You can further separate the players with a neat axis trick. I changed the date format to M/D, removing the year to reduce clutter in the charts I will now create. I've also inserted a new column A, which has the player names in the first row of each player's data.

If I select the yellow shaded areas and insert a line chart, I get the same chart as above. No surprise; it's the same data.

If I select all of the shaded areas, including blue and yellow areas, my inserted line chart will look like the second chart below. Each player has his own section of the axis, which is further divided into dates. This is clearer to read than the second chart above.

The column chart corresponding to this second line chart is the third chart below. Note that the overlap and gap width are both changed to 100.

[image: Further separate scores by player]

You could achieve the other separation on the axis, with date the major category and player the minor category. I've switched the Date and Player columns (if you do your formulas first, then drag the columns around, Excel adjusts the formulas so they still work). I've sorted by increasing date order, and I've inserted a new column A, this time with each date, only the first time it appears in column C. If you select the gray and yellow shaded areas, the chart is the same as the first line chart in the first example above.

If I select the blue and yellow shaded areas and insert a column chart, I get the second chart below (a line chart in this case is ugly and doesn't make much sense). Note that overlap and gap width are both 100.

[image]